# error octobercms:The avatar must be an image

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms, avatar

I have resized the user avatar with `intervention image` in account.php page from rainlab/user plugin ,i try to store it in the octobercms database like this code:

```
if (Input::hasFile('avatar')) {
    $file = Input::file('avatar');
    $filenamewithextension = $file->getClientOriginalName();

    //get filename without extension
    $filename = pathinfo($filenamewithextension, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

    //get file extension
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

    //filename to store
    $filenametostore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;

    Storage::put('public/profile_images/'. $filenametostore, fopen($file, 'r+'));
    Storage::put('public/profile_images/thumbnail/'. $filenametostore, fopen($file, 'r+'));

    //Resize image here
    $thumbnailpath ='storage/app/public/profile_images/thumbnail/'.$filenametostore;

    $img = Image::make($file->getRealPath());
    $img->crop(request('w'), request('h'), request('x1'), request('y1'));
    $img->save($thumbnailpath);
    $user->avatar = $filenametostore;
}
```

I get this error:

```
The avatar must be an image.
C:\wamp643\www\october3\vendor\october\rain\src\Database\Traits\Validation.php line 340
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the absolute path to the model relationship.

From the [docs](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/attachments#creating-attachments):

> You may also pass a string to the data attribute that contains an
>   absolute path to a local file.

```
$model->avatar = Input::file('file_input');
```

So in your case:

```
$user->avatar = Storage::get('public/profile_images/'. $filenametostore);
```